# Status bar cannot hide on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, toolbar

When I go fullscreen the status bar on chrome often freeze there, and is annoying the rest of the time. Do I really have to go back to Firefox ?

Comment: Can you please take a screenshot of the issue you are facing and upload it to http://imgur.com then add it as a comment or edit your question with the link.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything you don't want to do. This issue is a feature which has been asked for many times but it is [marked as wontfix](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45389). This is mandatory because it prevents websites from mimicking your desktop in order to snoop your passwords. I strongly believe that a better solution to this will come along soon (such as a highlight around the border instead of an annoying popup but until then Chrome users are stuck with it.

Comment: The link you have provided is only related to the "How to exit Fullscreen mode" instructions that appear when you enter fullscreen. This question doesn't appear to be asking about that at all.

Comment: I'm guessing that is exactly what was meant. A lot of people don't like that bubble and it often times doesn't go away when it should. The thing which is actually known as the status bar doesn't even really exist in Chrome and the tool tip which replaces it is fairly unobtrusive.

Comment: An old thread but still a problem - no, it's not about that Exit full screen bubble, it's about that annoying white line in the left bottom corner of Chrome, that often says "Waiting for xxxx.." and also shows link targets. It can get very distracting in full screen mode. See the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWbV_RhzJ_s  - the status bar even covers video navigation elements in full screen mode.